# Deselect nodes using cgSceneGraph 1.4.2

Tags: html, canvas

I would like to know if there is a way to deselect a node when something else happens, for example if I press a specific key or when an other event happen.

Also, is there a fast way to access the selected children nodes of a node which are selected? What I do now is use a loop to check each node if it is selected.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep that's possible.
you can use `this.cgSceneGeaph.setSelected(boolean)` method to select or deselect a node. A "onSelect" or "onDeselect" event will be then dispatched.

There is no way to directly access selected nodes of a parent node. There is a way to access the list of selected nodes in the scene.
On your main applicattion (inherited from CGSGScene), use :

```
this.selectedNodes; //array of selected nodes
```

This way you access all the selected nodes.

**EDIT :complete the code to show how to deselect the nodes**

Other way : use of a CGSGTraverser from the parent node you want to check:

```
var condition = function(node) {
    return node.isSelected === true;
};

var traverser = new CGSGTraverser();
var listSelectedNodes = traverser.traverse(myNode, condition, null);

for (var s = 0, len = listSelectedNodes.length; s < len; s++) {
    this.sceneGraph.deselectNode(listSelectedNodes[s]);
}
```

You can also have a look to the traverser [example on the web site](http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/examples.html).
Here is the link to the code:
http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/examples/04_Advanced/04_Traverser/js/class.main.js

Hope this can help :)

Comment: But how can I make a node deselected? Let's say that I have the node item which I can remove with "removeChild". When I do this, the selected border remains visible. I want to remove it too as soon as I remove a node.

Comment: Hi, which version of cgSceneGraph do you use ? 
A "quick and dirty" solution, waiting for the good one, is to first deselect it and then remove it (actually, that's what the framework does).

Comment: I use the 1.4.2. But how I deselect it?

Comment: Ok. I put the automatic deselect in the v2. 
To deselect, just use `myNode.setSelected(false);`

Comment: I do the following, but although that at "console.log" the item shows that is not selected, the resize handles are still visible. It seems that the selection of the node is cleared, but the selection border remains visible.

<pre><code>
var traverser = new CGSGTraverser();
var listSelectedNodes = traverser.traverse(root, checkSelected, null);    listSelectedNodes.forEach(function(item) {
  item.setSelected(false);
  console.log(item);
  root.removeChild(item);
  item.free;
});
</code></pre>

Comment: My mistake, the sceneGraph is responsible of (de)select the nodes. 
The code to use is 
`for (var s = 0, len = listSelectedNodes.length; s<len; s++) {
                this.sceneGraph.deselectNode(listSelectedNodes[s]);
            }`